# explicit globals per file in Typescript

Tags: typescript, global

I really liked the feature in jslint to have to declare all used globals in the beginning of a file like so:

```
/*global console, document */
```

is something like this possible in Typescript as well?
I got halfway there by setting the compiler option `--noLib`; the globals are no longer implicitly available. But how to continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No nothing like that can be done in a similar way with typescript. You can check if [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) has that functionality.

But more importantly, why is this needed? And why exclude the lib definitions with `--noLib`. What typescript is supposed to do for you is to make sure you are using libraries (and global libraries) in a correct way through typings. If you remove that with `--noLib` you are kind of missing the point.

The global libs will be there at run time (no matter what). What you can (and should do)is to define what runtime (and versions of ecmascript) you are targeting with typescript and through that make sure you are making the correct global libraries available to you.

If there is something specific you want to discourage you can use tslint for that, but that is not the use case for typescript.

Comment: This is wanted (not so much needed) to have a clear picture per file of what is used of the default libraries. I will look into slint for that

Comment: @Johan I got the name of the linter wrong it is not 'slint' but 'tslint'.